# WP query retrieve the src of attached image

Tags: wp-query, json, images

I'm encoding in JSON a bunch of data from a WP Query:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 20,
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'category' => 6,
    'meta_key' => 'custom_total_hits',
    'tag' => 'indie-pop',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'date_query' => array(
        'after' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-40 days')) 
    )
); 

$query = new WP_Query( $args ); 
$posts = $query->get_posts();   

foreach( $posts as $post ) {

    $output[] = array(

    'id' => $post->ID, 
    'title' => $post->post_title, 
    'count' => $post->custom_total_hits, 
    'soundcloud_url' => $post->soundcloud_song, 
    'soundcloud_id' => $post->soundcloud_ids, 
    'link' => get_permalink($post), 

    );
 }     

echo json_encode($output);
```

I would like to display in my JSON a key corresponding to the src of the medium size of the attached image. 
If I use `'images' => get_attached_media('image', $post->ID)` it retrieves an array of multiple data which I can not access since I don't know the ID of the attached image when I process the data of my JSON. How can I retrieve a first level `key : value` where the value is the src of the attached image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [wp_get_attachment_image_src](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/) and get your desired sized image and then pass onto your array :

```
foreach( $posts as $post ) {
    $imgsrc = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), "medium" );
    $imgsrc = $imgsrc[0];

    $output[] = array(

    'id' => $post->ID, 
    'title' => $post->post_title, 
    'count' => $post->custom_total_hits, 
    'soundcloud_url' => $post->soundcloud_song, 
    'soundcloud_id' => $post->soundcloud_ids, 
    'link' => get_permalink($post), 
    'image_src' => $imgsrc
    );
 }     

echo json_encode($output);
```